# Safari jquery select option .hide() alternative

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari

I have a jquery script which at first hide all select options:

```
$('option[data-start="1"]').hide();
```

and then shows options based on user select of other input.

```
$('option[data-variable1="' + variable1x + '"][data-variable2="' + variable2x + '"]').show();
```

Everything works great, but on Safari .hide() doesn't work.
I know about workaround:

```
$('option[data-start="1"]').prop('disabled', true);
$('option[data-variable1="' + variable1x + '"][data-variable2="' + variable2x + '"]').prop('disabled', false);
```

But this only turns off some options. I have dozens of options, so there is long list of inactive options.
I tried hiding inactive options, but Safari probably ignores this code:

```
select option[disabled="disabled"]{display:none !important;width:0;height:0;visibility: hidden;opacity:0;}
select option:disabled { display:none !important;height:0;width:0;visibility: hidden;opacity:0;}
```

Could you help me with some workaround for Safari?

Comment: I imagine that any cross-platform customization of the native `<select>` is going to be an uphill battle.  Taking a step back from the task and looking at the goal, your best bet is probably to no longer use a native `<select>` and instead use a plugin that builds a custom select-like interface.  For jQuery popular choices include Select2 and Chosen.

Answer (score 0):

to get a full browser compatible to hide and show elements
try to use the `hidden` attribute
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden

to use it in your code to hide `option`

```
$('option[data-start="1"]').attr('hidden','hidden');
```

and to show an `option` use

```
$('option[data-start="1"]').removeAttr('hidden','hidden');
```

here a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zj2kLxc8/1/

Comment: I tested this on lambdatest.com on Safari 12 and this doesn't work. All options are visible on start.

Comment: Changing the value of the CSS display property on an element with the hidden attribute overrides the behavior. For instance, elements styled display: flex will be displayed despite the hidden attribute's presence.

Comment: but your example od jsfiddle also doesn't work on Safari 12.